# Spot erroneous row data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
 head(data)
              V1      V2  V3 V4    V5  V6    V7     
1 458263182005000000 1941 2 14 -73.90 38.60 US009239
2 451063182005000002 1941 2 14 -74.00 36.90 US009239
3 447463182005000000 1941 2 14 -74.00 35.40 US009239
4 443863182105000000 1941 2 15 -74.00 34.00 US009239
5 436663182105000001 1941 2 15 -74.00 32.60 US009239
6 433063182105000000 1941 2 15 -73.80 31.70 US009239
```

but when I do

```
data <- read.table("data.dat",header=F,sep=";")
```

I get this error

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  could not allocate memory (2048 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'
```

How can I determine in which row something is going wrong (e.g. the format is different)?

Many thanks

Comment: Try passing `colClasses` explicitly or use `fread` from data.table. There is no row where something goes wrong. You are running out of memory. I assume your file is pretty big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R says can not allocate memory. So you can check how large is the dataset and your computer memory.

Answer (score 0):

despite this is an old question...
I think R_AllocStringBuffer
 does not have to do with the overall memory of your computer. Which is also the optionen in this thread:

[R could not allocate memory on ff procedure. How come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210578/r-could-not-allocate-memory-on-ff-procedure-how-come)

Maybe check the delimiter "," or ";". It seems to create a huge string...